# create json model and api for array of object in android

Tags: php, android, json

I want to create JSON model and API for array of JSON object.
my PHP code:

```
<?php
$response = array();
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';
$db = new DB_CONNECT();
if (isset($_POST['type'])) {
$type = $_POST['type'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM bidsproject WHERE type='$type'
 ORDER BY createTime ") ;
 if (mysql_num_rows($result)>0) {
$response["products"] = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $product = array();
    $product["projectId"] = $row["projectId"];
    $product["title"] = $row["title"];
    $product["createTime"] = $row["createTime"];
    array_push($response["products"], $product);
   }
   echo json_encode($response);
   } 
   else {
    }
     }
   else {
  }
    ?>
```

and my JSON model:

```
   public class browsprojectJm {
  int success;
public int getSuccess() {
    return success;
}
public void setSuccess(int success) {
    this.success = success;
}
  DataToken project;
public class DataToken{
    int projectId;
    String title;
    String creaeteTime;
    public int getId() {
        return projectId;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.projectId = id;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getDate() {
        return creaeteTime;
    }
    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.creaeteTime=date;
    }
    }
   }
```

and my API:

```
     @FormUrlEncoded
     @POST("project/searchBidProject.php")
     Call<List<browsprojectJm>> browsproject(@Field("type") int  
      type_register);
```

output with postman:

```
{
"products": [
    {
        "projectId": "1",
        "title": "خرید خانه",
        "createTime": "2018-09-05"
    },
    {
        "projectId": "3",
        "title": "خرید خانه شخصی",
        "createTime": "2018-09-05"
    },
    {
        "projectId": "4",
        "title": "خرید من",
        "createTime": "2018-09-05"
    }
]
 }
```

but this not working and i don't know  what's wrong. it fails without errors but I think this problem is from JSON model or api.I'm new in android developing and please explain for me clearly

Comment: For the PHP side, you will want to stop using `mysql_*` functions and switch to `mysqli_*` or PDO. Also, whichever you use, you will want to utilize prepared statements to safeguard against SQL injection attacks. (I cannot help with the android side of things, not my area heh)

Comment: can You please post the json  that  the php is sending

Comment: i do this, you can check and help me

Comment: I think there's something wrong with your model , try adding this adding this plugin to AndroidStudio and generate your model  using it https://github.com/robohorse/RoboPOJOGenerator

Comment: thank's. it help me very well